# How can I get a Mongodb collection create script?

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, collections, migration, generate

I have a spring boot application rest api with mongodb as database.

My own application created all the collections in mongodb, but I really need the db.createCollection script.

There is anyway to get this? Like SQL Server?
I'm reading about migration but i don't know the best way.

Can you help me to find the best way?

Comment: Actually you don't need to create any collection. A collection is automatically created when you insert anything or create an index.

Comment: If you really need the script, execute `db.createCollection` from the mongo shell.  (yes, without any parenthesis)